# Display result of linq query randomly in listview in Asp.net C#

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

```
var getquest = (from q in dc.Exam_Questions
                            where q.ExamNumber == int.Parse(Examnumber)
                            select new
                            {
                                QuestionTitle = q.QuestionTitle,
                                correctanswers = q.correctanswers,
                                ID = q.ID,
                            });
ListView1.DataSource = getquest;
ListView1.DataBind();
```

How to display result of linq query randomly in listview in Asp.net C#?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a random data by adding a guid property to your query. After that you order the result by this new property.

```
 var getquest = (from q in dc.Exam_Questions
                        where q.ExamNumber == int.Parse(Examnumber)
                        select new
                        {
                            RandomId = Guid.NewGuid(),
                            QuestionTitle = q.QuestionTitle,
                            correctanswers = q.correctanswers,
                            ID = q.ID,

                        });
        ListView1.DataSource = getquest.OrderBy(p => p.RandomId).ToList();
        ListView1.DataBind();
```

Comment: not change the order of exam questions ,and not order Randomly

Comment: It works for me. Check if you do not set some properties on your ListView that may impact my solution.

Comment: RandomId  must Add in listview_ItemDataBound or not?

Comment: What is a properties on your ListView ?

Comment: You must not add RamdomId  listview_ItemDataBound.